# Eclipse: Hover broken in debug perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, hover

Since upgrading Eclipse (Galileo build 20090920-1017), hover in debug no longer displays a variable's value. Instead, hover behaves as if I were in normal Java perspective:

[alt text http://michaelzanussi.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/debug_hover.png](http://michaelzanussi.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/debug_hover.png)

I've tried cleaning the project, re-importing it, etc., all to no avail. Anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I went to Window - Preferences - Java - Editor - Hovers, hit "Restore Defaults" and "Apply" and that fixed it for me, even though nothing actually changed in the settings...

Comment: This works great and is the quickest solution. If you're running your app in debug mode and notice hover isn't working, hit the red stop button, follow Dale's instructions, then relaunch your app in debug mode. No need to rebuild or anything.

Comment: A better solution than mine, as KomodoDave suggests. Thanks Dale77.

Answer (score 10):

Go to Window - Preferences - Java - Editor - Hovers.

1. Is "Combined Hover" selected? Uncheck it; apply; close the window; **restart** debugging session; go back; check it again; apply.
2. If the above doesn't help, you can check "Variable Values" option and specify a modifier key for it. Not as convenient as "combined", but should work.

Comment: Item #1 is one of the first things I checked early on, and just tried again per your suggestion. No change. However, I am not seeing "Variable Values" option under Hovers.

Comment: Well, therein lies your problem :-) If 'Variable Values' is not listed, it's not included into 'Combined Hover' either. I have no idea  why it would not be listed, though... Are you using any 3rd-party plugins? Have you tried reinstalling Eclipse?

Comment: No third-party plug-ins, I'm using Eclipse straight out-of-the-box. I've also tried re-installing twice. No change. The "Variable Values" missing option is key here, I believe, so I'm heading down that path now.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too once, I "just" had to restart eclipse, after that the hover mechanism worked again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was "fixed" by renaming the package.

For whatever reason, this refactoring triggered something in Eclipse, and immediately I was able to view variable values during debugging. Also, when I go back into Preferences under Hovers, I can now see the "Variable Values" option.

Comment: Solution by Dale77 is quicker than this and requires no code change.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and when I came across this question.  My problem was that windows hover time was set to 20s or so (you can test if this is your problem by putting the mouse on a mistake and waiting for a min or so).  The registry key "MouseHoverTime" was set to a large value of 200000 ms (normally 400).  Fix it by going to start -> run -> "regedit" -> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse double click "MouseHoverTime" and setting it back to 400.

I think this had been done on my computer a while back to prevent hover popups in another program.  Anyway, sorry that my answer doesn't directly apply to this question, but I'm hoping it'll help somebody like me that comes across this thread with a similar issue.

Comment: Good to know but in that case it would not only affect eclipse

Answer (score -1):

For C++ project, please add -ggdb -0g to the compiler option. Hope this solution can help eveyry C++ programer face with the same issue.