# Why is Eclipse not showing values of all objects in the Debug perspective?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-jdt

When debugging a Java application in Eclipse JDT, values of some variables are displayed in the Variables view but not in tooltips when hovering over the variables in the editor.

The following screenshot illustrates the problem:

[image]

As you can see a tooltip with a variable value is shown for `this`. However no tooltip (or the one containing only declaration in case of Combined Hover) is shown for `key` while the Variables view shows values for both `this` and `key`.

I've tried Combined Hover and Variable Values in Java/Editors/Hovers as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1730628/471164) with a similar effect. The only difference is that Combined Hover shows declaration in a tooltip when Variable Values doesn't show a tooltip at all.

Comment: You actually hovered the mouse right over the `key` variable and it did not display a tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Eclipse reported [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317045).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be working with an unsaved file (a star next to the file name). Try saving the file + rebuilding your project, then relaunch.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately saving doesn't help.

Comment: OK, so, there is enough info for the Variables view but not for the tooltip thing. Which version of Eclipse are you using? Have you tried this with an earlier/later one?

Comment: I am using version 3.7.2 and this issue was in some older versions that I used as well.

Comment: Hmm... Could be a bug worth reporting against JDT. Well, you can debug your Eclipse instance and see if this is so :)

Comment: Maybe I'll give it (debugging Eclipse) a try when I have more time. For now I've just localized the issue and added a comment to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317045 . Thanks anyway.