# Eclipse debugger hover produces empty box, no variable value

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm debugging a Java (Android) application in Eclipse Indigo.   In the debug perspective, if I'm stopped at a breakpoint, when I hover over a variable to see its value it displays a blank, white box (where I assume the variable's value is supposed to appear?) but with no content.   It does not seem to matter what kind of a variable it is, local or class-scope, static or instance, the box is just as blank.

I can see the variables I need to see in the variables tab of the debugger perspective, but it would be a lot more convenient to see them by hovering.

In Preferences>Java>Editor>Hovers I've tried it with both Variable Values and Combined Hover with no improvement.  I'm running on Windows 7, if that matters.

**N.B.**  I have read this thread:  [Eclipse: Hover broken in debug perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730628/eclipse-hover-broken-in-debug-perspective)

Answer (score 1):

Try to hit the restore defaults as described in [Eclipse: Hover broken in debug perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730628/eclipse-hover-broken-in-debug-perspective). Make sure to stop your debug run and restart.

You might also check Eclipse's [Debug view documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-debug_view.htm).

Comment: Restore Defaults didn't make any difference.  I probably should have mentioned that before I posted my question I tried everything in that thread except refactoring, which seemed unnecessarily risky+speculative.  I'll edit that in.

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring a package in your project then trying it again.

Could also be a bug
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=357127
Which version are you using?

Comment: The bug in your link was against the Mac.  In any case according to the log they fixed it for 3.7.2, which is the version I'm running.   Not sure why refactoring would help and it seems dangerous to refactor an otherwise perfectly good project just as an experiment.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same thing on Ubuntu. I am using the program VcXSrv on my Windows 10 system to get program windows from Ubuntu.
I had to turn off The 'Native opengl' option in the XLauncher when starting VcXSrv to get the hover text to appear.